# How to convert Content of http request to UTF-8 in R?

Tags: r, api

Would like to access the content of a word document from API using R. Have challenges reading the content after several attempts. I guess I might be missing something....

```
library(httr)
require(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(reqres)

# 
result <- POST(url,
               body = request_body_json,
               add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json")),
               authenticate(user, passwd))
```

```
> result
Response [http://myServer/theservice/v0001/restun/GetDocumentStreamRaw]
  Date: 2020-05-05 08:43
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  Size: 11.4 kB
<BINARY BODY>
```

Attempts on getting content:

```
> content(result) # same as content(result, "raw",encoding = "UTF-8")
   [1] 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 df a4 d2 6c 5a 01 00 00 20 05 00 00 13 00 08 02 5b 43
  [33] 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73 5d 2e 78 6d 6c 20 a2 04 02 28 a0 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [65] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  [97] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [129] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [161] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [193] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [225] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [257] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [289] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [321] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [353] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [385] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [417] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [449] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [481] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [513] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [545] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 b4 94 cb 6e c2 30 10
 [577] 45 f7 95 fa 0f 91 b7 55 62 e8 a2 aa 2a 02 8b 3e 96 2d 52 e9 07 18 7b 02 56 fd 92 c7 bc fe be 13
 [609] 02 51 55 01 91 0a 6c 22 25 33 f7 de 33 56 c6 83 d1 da 9a 6c 09 11 b5 77 25 eb 17 3d 96 81 93 5e
 [641] 69 37 2b d9 d7 e4 2d 7f 64 19 26 e1 94 30 de 41 c9 36 80 6c 34 bc bd 19 4c 36 01 30 23 b5 c3 92
 [673] cd 53 0a 4f 9c a3 9c 83 15 58 f8 00 8e 2a 95 8f 56 24 7a 8d 33 1e 84 fc 16 33 e0 f7 bd de 03 97
 [705] de 25 70 29 4f b5 07 1b 0e 5e a0 12 0b 93 b2 d7 35 7d 6e 48 22 18 64 d9 73 d3 58 67 95 4c 84 60
 [737] b4 14 89 ea 7c e9 d4 9f 94 7c 97 50 90 72 db 83 73 1d f0 8e 1a 18 3f 98 50 57 8e 07 ec 74 1f 74
 [769] 34 51 2b c8 c6 22 a6 77 61 a9 8b af 7c 54 5c 79 b9 b0 a4 2c 4e db 1c e0 f4 55 a5 25 b4 fa da 2d
 [801] 44 2f 01 91 ce dc 9a a2 ad 58 a1 dd 9e ff 28 07 a6 8d 01 bc 3c 45 e3 db 1d 0f 29 91 e0 1a 00 3b
 [833] e7 4e 84 15 4c 3f af 46 f1 cb bc 13 a4 a2 dc 89 98 1a b8 3c 46 6b dd 09 91 68 03 a1 79 f6 cf e6
 [865] d8 da 9c 8a a4 ce 71 f4 01 69 a3 e3 3f c6 de af 6c ad ce 69 e0 00 31 e9 d3 7f 5d 9b 48 d6 67 cf
 [897] 07 f5 6d a0 40 1d c8 e6 db fb 6d f8 03 00 00 ff ff 03 00 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21
 [929] 00 1e 91 1a b7 ef 00 00 00 4e 02 00 00 0b 00 08 02 5f 72 65 6c 73 2f 2e 72 65 6c 73 20 a2 04 02
 [961] 28 a0 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [993] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 10426 entries ]
```

```
> content(result, "parsed",encoding = "UTF-8")
Error: No automatic parser available for application/octet-stream.
```

Other attempts:

```
> my_content <- result$content
> readBin(gzcon(rawConnection(my_content)), what = "character")
[1] "PK\003\004\024"
```

```
> readChar(content(result), nchars=length(content(result)))
Error in readChar(content(result), nchars = length(content(result))) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\006\0\b\0\0\0!\0ß¤ÒlZ\001\0\0 \005\0\0\023\0\b\002[Content_Types].xml ¢\004\002( \0\002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
```

**You can access link to `content(result)` here**: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brainy749/testdata/master/result_content.txt

The **expected human readable content** is `Test OCR via API`.

Any help? Many thanks.

Comment: Without any more information, I doubt anyone can help you. Are you sure you're even getting a word document? All I see is a bunch of hex data, but that could be pretty much anything.

Comment: I'm trying to access content of documents via the ThereFore API. Link: https://therefore.net/help/2018/en-us/AR/SDK/WebAPI/the_webapi_operation_getdocumentstreamraw.html

Comment: @SergioRomero I have updated with additional info

Comment: That's the content of your Word doc. Save it and open it in Word, and you should be able to see what's inside. To open it in R, try something like officer

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide a reproducible example, I'm wildly guessing, but maybe it helps:

```
library(httr)

res = POST(url,
           body = request_body_json,
           add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json")),
           authenticate(user, passwd))
tmp = tempfile()
writeBin(res$content, tmp)
# maybe unzip here?
read_docx(tmp) # what function do you use to read the word file
# OR directly
read_docx(res$content)
```

- Can you provide a working URL?
- How do you want to read the file content?

Comment: @Brainy749 ok, still hard since, I can't access the API. Have you tried `writeBin` and then reading from the file? Maybe also `readBin`? Also don't get what format you are getting back.

Comment: I had a somewhat related issue some time ago. Maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135794
I also had to parse from raw binary data.

Comment: I tried the  `readBin(content(result),what =  "character" )` and then outputs `"PK\003\004\024"` `.

Comment: You can access a copy of the `content(result)` output via [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brainy749/testdata/master/result_content.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brainy749/testdata/master/result_content.txt).